# Expose a Custom Hook to Children (children only) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript, react-custom-hooks, react-children

I'm not sure the title is correct, so let me try to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Let's say I have a flow in my application that has 3 steps in it, so I create a component (let's call it `Stepper`) with 3 child components where each child is a component that renders the corresponding step.

I want to expose a custom hook to the child components of `Stepper`, let's call it `useStepper`.

This is how `Stepper` would look like (JSX-wise):

```
export const Stepper = (props) => {

...some logic

  return (
   <SomeWrapper>
      {props.children}
   </SomeWrapper>
  );
};
```

so I can make components like this:

```
export SomeFlow = () => {
   return (
      <Stepper>
         <StepOne />
         <StepTwo />
         <StepThree />
      </Stepper>
   );
};
```

Now this is how I want things to work inside `Stepper`'s children, let's take `StepThree` as an example:

```
export const StepThree = () => {
   const exposedStepperData = useStepper();

   ... some logic

   return (
      ...
   );
};
```

Now, it's **important** that the `Stepper` will be **reusable**; That means - each `Stepper` instance should have its own data/state/context that is exposed through the `useStepper` hook.
Different Stepper instances should have different exposed data.

Is it possible to achieve this? I tried to use Context API but I was not successful. It's also weird that I couldn't find anything about it on the internet, maybe I searched wrong queries as I don't know what patten it is (if it exists).

***Note:***
I achieved a similar behavior through injected props from parent to its children, but it's not as clean as I want it to be, especially with Typescript.

Comment: What do you mean by expose? No other component can use it? Then you can define in the same file as the component file right and not expose it

Comment: But how do I expose it only to the children? I want each stepper to expose its data to its children with a hook. See the `StepThree` example.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across something like this, it was solved by pouring all the components/steps in an array and let the hook manage which component/step to show. If you want it to be more reusable you could pass in the `children` to the array.

I hope this helps you in the right direction

useStepper.ts

```js
import { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

export const useStepper = (steps: ReactElement[]) => {
  const [currentStepIndex, setCurrentStepIndex] = useState(0);

  const next = () => {
    setCurrentStepIndex((i: number) => {
      if (i >= steps.length - 1) return i;
      return i + 1;
    });
  };

  const back = () => {
    setCurrentStepIndex((i: number) => {
      if (i <= 0) return i;
      return i - 1;
    });
  };

  const goTo = (index: number) => {
    setCurrentStepIndex(index);
  };

  return {
    currentStepIndex,
    step: steps[currentStepIndex],
    steps,
    isFirstStep: currentStepIndex === 0,
    isLastStep: currentStepIndex === steps.length - 1,
    goTo,
    next,
    back,
  };
};
```

Stepper.tsx

```js
// const { currentStepIndex, step, isFirstStep, isLastStep, back, next } =
//  useStepper([<StepOne />, <StepTwo />, <StepThree />]);

const { currentStepIndex, step, isFirstStep, isLastStep, back, next } =
  useStepper([...children]);

return (
  <div>
    {!isFirstStep && <button onClick={back}>Back</button>}
    {step}
    <button onClick={next}>{isLastStep ? "Finish" : "Next"}</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's actually pretty much what I did. The thing is, let's say I'm at the last step, and I want to control what to do when the user clicks on "Finish". The problem is that the "Finish" button is defined on the parent component, but I need to control the behavior of the Finish's onClick based on the current step's data. For example - make a post request of a form in the last step when the user clicks on "Finish". So, for now I inject the data to the children from the parent component, so I can set an "onFinish" callback from the children, but I'm looking for a clean way

Comment: I see your problem now, maybe it is an option to define the `Stepper` as  a ContextProvider and then you can create the useStepper and get all the data via the context?

Comment: That's what I initially tried to do, but then it ruins the reusability of the Stepper. I thought of making a function that will return the stepper and its context, but then it's not really intuitive to use and the developer will have to configure things before actually using the stepper. I'm looking for a more automatic & intuitive way to do it, if there is any way.

Comment: So as I am understanding the `Stepper` needs to be reuseable, it needs to handle going to the next/previous step and you want to have the data used in the children accessible for all the children/steps. The children/steps can be anything right?

Comment: @RubenSmh Exactly. But the `Stepper` is just an example of a problem I have; I'd actually want to know if it's possible regardless to this specific problem, and if yes - to learn this pattern, it'd make so many coding problems so much easier for me.